# Shell | Sort Date and Month in Ascending order

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I wanted to display/sort the file records in Ascending order of Date and Month or if there are any equal data values they should list in the very next column in ascending order.

**Date & Month to sort:** (current scenario)

- ver.....03.02../ver>
- ver.....19.01../ver>
- ver.....02.02..ver>

**File content**:

- ver>0.1.1-ABC-XYA-BR-***03.02***-v1.0-1-4d4f3dd/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-XYZ-LOK-BR-***19.01***-v1.0-5-8a8d7dd/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-DXD-UIJ-BR-***02.02***-v1.0-4-9o2k4wk/ver>

**How would I can achieve below following results?**

- ver>0.1.1-XYZ-LOK-BR-**19.01**-v1.0-5-8a8d7dd/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-DXD-UIJ-BR-**02.02**-v1.0-4-9o2k4wk/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-ABC-XYA-BR-**03.02**-v1.0-1-4d4f3dd/ver>

I tried using sort: (not working)
`sort -n sortfile.txt`

- ver>0.1.1-DXD-UIJ-BR-**02.02**-v1.0-4-9o2k4wk/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-ABC-XYA-BR-**03.02**-v1.0-1-4d4f3dd/ver>
- ver>0.1.1-XYZ-LOK-BR-**19.01**-v1.0-5-8a8d7dd/ver>

Comment: Are those filenames in a file system (e.g. as displayed via an `ls`) or are these strings inside a file?

Comment: These are strings inside a file

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort`, but you will need to specify the field-seperator `-t '-'` so that fields are separated by `'-'` and then specify the *keydef* to sort on the 5th field beginning with the 4th character and then again with the 1st character and finally a version sort on field 6 if all else is equal. That would be:

```
sort -t '-' -k5.4n -k5.1n -k6V  contents
```

Providing full start and stop characters within each keydef can be done as:

```
sort -t '-' -k5.4n,5.5 -k5.1n,5.2 -k6V  contents
```

(though for this data the output isn't changed)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sort -t '-' -k5.4n -k5.1n -k6V  contents
ver>0.1.1-XYZ-LOK-BR-19.01-v1.0-5-8a8d7dd/ver>
ver>0.1.1-DXD-UIJ-BR-02.02-v1.0-4-9o2k4wk/ver>
ver>0.1.1-ABC-XYA-BR-03.02-v1.0-1-4d4f3dd/ver>
```

Comment: Thanks, @David for your inputs - Strings are getting sorted in ascending order.